# How can make my own cocoapods on GitLab instead of GitHub?

Tags: github, repository, cocoapods, gitlab, private

I wanna make **private** repository for my own **cocoapod** but **Github** needs ***payment plan*** for let me keep on.

So I wanna know can I do this via **Gitlab**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the same process as the one described in "[XCode + Gitlab + Cocoapods or How I modularised my iOS source code](https://medium.com/@jon_nmn/xcode-gitlab-cocoapods-or-how-i-modularised-my-ios-source-code-3e6f8777e4ce)" by **[Jonathan Neumann](https://twitter.com/jon_nmn)**.

Jonathan is using GitLab.

> Create a specsrepo project within that group. This repository will host the podspecs that describe each of your modules. A podspec basically tells cocoapods what to install, and where to find it.
>   Do the same for the main project and one of its modules. Let’s call the projects TopProject and Submodule1

[image: https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1000/1*j7O4P25enETpZigu4jPe8Q.png]

Comment: Ssh URLs are well supported in cocoapod since 2014 with https://github.com/CocoaPods/Core/pull/84 and https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2534